# How to make PageControl occupy full screen when form is maximized at Delphi

Tags: delphi

At Delphi form (780 * 472) I put a PageControl with same dimension (780 * 472). At run time when form is maximized PageControl is not occupying full screen as shown in figure below. How to make PageControl occupy full screen when form is maximized.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the **anchor**(if you are on FireMonkey instead of VCL look at **Margins** and **Padding** properties) property of the PAgeControl to allow the auto resize of the component. Take a look at [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNWcy8S2k4Y) for more information.

Comment: You can also set `Align` to `alClient`.